# CSS Sprites for Fluid Grid System

Tags: css, css-sprites

Is there a way to use sprites without using the

```
background: url();
```

property?

For example, is there a way to use sprites with

```
<img>
```

tags instead?

The reason I ask is because I am trying to use CSS sprites in a fluid grid system and I need to be able to control the max-width of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're wondering if you can crop an image various times in different spots? 
Yes it is possible. Here are a few posts explaining these techniques:

http://tjkdesign.com/articles/how-to_use_sprites_with_my_Image_Replacement_technique.asp
http://www.artzstudio.com/2010/04/img-sprites-high-contrast/

Comment: Thank you!  I haven't finished reading it but it looks promising!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!